# How to stop animation when listview is reloading in iOS xamarin form?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My app has some strange animation when my list view is reloading data and it only happens to iOS. It looks like a new cell insert into the list view every times it reloads.

How can I stop that from happening?

Do I need to work on the custom render to solve this case? and how can I do it?

The code to reload data:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            if (App.AuthenticationContext == null)
            {
                DialogHelper.ShowLoading("");
                if (!App.Reconnect())
                {
                    Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage(new LoginViewModel()));
                    DialogHelper.HideLoading();
                    return;
                }

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        ReloadData();
                    });
                    DialogHelper.HideLoading();
                });
            }
            ViewModel.CurrentAuthenticationContext = App.AuthenticationContext;
        }
```

Comment: You are not reusing the cell the right way . Could you post the related code ?

Comment: I put the the where I reload the data.